# How to export bookmark list from stock android(ICS) browser to pc

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, stock-android

I have been using the stock browser which came with the phone for awhile and it has been really useful. Currently I have a large number of articles I have bookmarked that I would somehow like to get on my PC. I tried to use the "share" functionality but it allows you to share only one link at a time, and I have over 50 articles. Is there any way to export the entire list?

Comment: What phone do you have? Manufacturers tend to customize the web browser so the answer is different from one phone to another.

Comment: @DanHulme I flashed ICS on it myself, It's the stock android browser.

Answer (score 1):

Using  "[Bookmarks Sort and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.happydroid.bookmarks)"
you can copy your bookmarks from the default Android Browser to your SD Card Directory ( */mnt/sdcard/BookmarkSB/* ).   The filename will include a datetimestamp so you can easily tell which file you just created.  They  are regular bookmarks.html  formatted  Netscape bookmarks files that can be imported into any browser or viewed in any browser.

You can view the file with any File Explorer app by opening the folder  BookmarkSB  (*/mnt/sdcard/BookmarkSB/*) then open the file you just created with Browser or any other browser.

**One way to copy the created file to your PC:**
You can use an app such as "[3CX Droid Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm)"
Download the file from your tablet to your PC.

1. Invoke 3CX Droid on tablet,
2. open the url in a browser on your PC   i.e.  *http://192.168.0.xxx:8080*
3. then in File Explorer within 3CX Droid viewed on your PC, open the folder on the tablet select your file,
4. then use 'download' on the 3CS Droid File Explorer menu  which will save your file on the downloads folder used by your browser,  the shortcut to view your downloaded files is probably "Ctrl+J" on your PC.
5. Open the HTML bookmarks file

FWIW  if you were to import into another Android browser that cannot sort bookmarks you would want to sort bookmarks in your default browser in reverse order before you export.  Rearranging bookmarks one bookmark  at a time would be very tedious.   This is assuming that import inserts them  one at a time at the top of your bookmarks instead of at the bottom.